# Selling an NFT art

Tags: nft

I'm very new to NFT world. I saw a post on OpenSea selling an NFT art. I think it has many copies since I saw it's owned by multiple people already. If I buy that art as well, can it still be sold to others once all the copies have been sold by the creator?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can freely transfer your ERC-721 and ERC-1155 tokens to other users. Once it is in your crypto wallet you can list it for sale on OpenSea and set your own price (or put it out for auction), otherwise you can go to other marketplaces or transfer it directly wherever you like.